# Django rest framework custom serializer using foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

```
class MyModel():
    # fields

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = MyModel

class CustomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    comment = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    mymodel = MyModelSerializer() #?? here is the problem
```

I want to create an API which will take two arguments, first a valid MyModel instance id (from dropdown in browsable api page) and second is a `comment`.

I tried above approach but didn't show dropdown in my html. apart from this I tried `RelatedField` with `many=True` and some other possible approach.

in the end my api will take two input, an ID (MyModel object) and a comment.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#multiplechoicefield

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use something like:

```
class CustomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    comment = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    mymodel = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=list(MyModel.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)))
```

Comment: Trying this on a ForeignKey field (client_id), but getting `Object of type Client is not JSON serializable`